# How to retrieve the percentage of people who selected something in the application from Cloud Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner programmer, I am creating a mobile application that simulates the course of the European football championship where the user completes the results of the group stage matches one by one (there are a total of 6 groups - in each group there are 4 teams that play a total of 6 matches). I would like to introduce a database functionality (using Cloud Firestore for this), which, after the user enters and accepts the result of a given match, will display to the user how a given match is typed by other users (i.e. how many % of users typed the win of team A, how many % of users typed the win of team B, and how many % of users typed a draw in a given match).

In the ViewModel, I created a special function to save the result of a given match in the database:

```
private val firestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun storePrediction(
        group: String,
        matchIndex: Int,
        prediction: EuroMatchResult
    ) {
        val matchRef = firestoreRef.collection("predictions").document(group).collection("matches").document("match$matchIndex")
        matchRef.set(prediction)
    }
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right: firstly, if I created the documents and collections in Firestore correctly, and secondly, I'm not sure if I should really save the result of the entire match, maybe I should just save the number instead of the whole result, (for example, if the user bets win of team A: so if scoreA > scoreB, write it as 1, win of team B as 2, and draw as 3)? Then I would count the numbers 1,2,3 and compare them to all the written numbers.
Moreover, I am not sure how to display these percentage results. I was thinking of something like this:

```
        predictions.collect {prediction ->
            val total = prediction.size.toFloat()
            val teamAPercentage = (prediction.count {it.scoreA > it.scoreB} / total) * 100
            val teamBPercentage = (prediction.count {it.scoreA < it.scoreB} / total) * 100
            val drawPercentage = (prediction.count {it.scoreA == it.scoreB} / total) * 100
        }
```

But I'm not convinced about this idea. I will be very grateful for your help. I am inserting a link to the entire screen code and ViewModel code below:
https://pastebin.mozilla.org/UGtxb94a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the ViewModel, I created a special function to save the result of a given match in the database

If you want to use MVVM architecture in your app, most likely you should consider creating a repository class and performing all operations there. Then inside your ViewModel class only collect the result and send it further to the UI.

> For example, if the user bets win of team A: so if scoreA > scoreB, write it as 1, win of team B as 2, and draw as 3.

Suppose you have a document for each game. Inside each document, I would save the result of the game in a single field called `result`. So if scoreA > scoreB, write it as 1, win of team B as 2, and draw as 0. If you want to check a user prediction against the real result, you only have to use an if statement and save the prediction perhaps in a document that is associated with the game. Now, to know the percentage of predictions, simply store two more fields inside the user document. The number of total games the user predicted and the number of correct predictions. In this way, you'll always know how many correct predictions a user made from a total of x games. For such an incrementation I recommend you use [FieldValue.increment(1)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value).